# Laravel: composer says it has installed library and updated composer.json but

Tags: php, composer-php, twilio

but when I go to composer.json, the library ain't there showing.

I just wrote this:

```
php composer.phar require twilio/sdk
```

and I could see the typical running of dependencies and versions being installed 
and I even updated it to make sure it had actually installed it (otherwise it would complain nothing ain't there) but

when I went to routes and wrote this:

```
Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'), '/sms', function()
{
  $twiml = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
  $twiml->say('Hello - sorry to ring in the WC', array('voice' => 'alice'));
  $response = Response::make($twiml, 200);
  $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  return $response;
});
```

it says it can't find the class, so, either twilio is hiding from every predator or I don't know what.

Question:

So, eventually I would need to know the exact syntax to be added to the config app service providers but I can only find syntax for other libraries related to twilio which are not the official libraries for laravel and I d rather use twilio/sdk and not any other.

What would be the syntax for both the service provider and the alias façade?

Comment: When you install something in Laravel, you need to: Add service provider and if you want, an alias to the Class, so you don't have to require the whole namespace. Did you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's se.... And do you know what's the namespace? Because all you need in that case is at the top of the file:

```
use Path\To\Namespace\Class
```

and that's all... Or...

```
$twiml = New Path\To\Namespace\Services_Twilio_Twiml();
```

Comment: yes, I was thinking about something like that, but since I just copied and pasted a tutorial step by step where the only thing it does is add that to the routes without anything else, apparently it worked in his case, but I had  added no controller no nothing yet.

Comment: This tutorial:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/09/getting-started-with-twilio-and-the-laravel-framework-for-php.html

Comment: Are you using Laravel 5.X ? Because in Laravel 4.2 (the one he's using) it does something called Dependency Injection, and you don't have to 'use' or write the Whole Namespace. It's different in L 5.X, where you HAVE TO, or add the Aliases and Service providers.

Comment: alright! you are right, yes, ! that explains it all, I am using 5.1 yes, in fact I have lots of libraries where I do use the namespace stuff or the \ but yes, that is the reason.. Thank you a lot for everything you have really helped. Gracias.